# How to wait on injected script in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I am testing an application that makes use of native es6 modules, so I have `<script type="module">import...do things...</script>` whenever I need some JS. Since modules don't expose themselves globally, I need to manually expose their contents to `window` to do stubbing with Cypress. I can successfully append the script I need onto `document.body`, but to see its effects I need to add arbitrary `cy.wait(n ~= 100)`. Is there a way to wait on / know when an injected script has been parsed and run?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [dedicated Promise utility in Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise).

> Use `Cypress.Promise` to create promises. Cypress is promise aware so if you return a promise from inside of commands like `.then()`, Cypress will not continue until those promises resolve.

Resolve the promise when the script has loaded (`script.onload`):

```js
cy.get('head').then(($head) => {
  const script = document.createElement('script')
  $head.append(script)
  const promise = new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {
    script.onload = resolve
  })
  script.src = 'http://place.of/script.js'
  return promise
})
```

Instead of using an external script file, you can of course also set the content that you have in the question.

```js
  script.type = 'module'
  script.text = 'import...do things...'
```

What’s important is that you first add the `script` tag to the DOM, then add the promise resolution to the `onload` event, and only then set the script source or content. Otherwise, it can be that the `onload` event triggers before you have attached the promise resolution to it.